# Как подключиться к серверу по ssh, имея его приватный ключ?

Tags: linux, ssh

Есть сервер, есть его приватный ключ, как подключиться к нему по ssh?

Comment: В putty имеется такая функция. https://it-wiki.org.ua/unix/ssh_keys_for_authentication_via_putty

Comment: Что такое «приватный ключ сервера»?

Comment: если под «приватным ключом сервера» подразумевается `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` (или аналогичный для других протоколов шифрования), то он ни как не поможет подключиться к серверу...

Comment: имеется в виду файл id_rsa

Comment: Ключ сервера вам не нужен. Вам надо на машине с которой будет происходить подключение создать пару ключей. созданный id_rsa оставить на месте. А содержимое  id_rsa.pub со своей машины записать на сервер к которому будете подключаться в .ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Спасибо, это обычный способ. Но другого доступа к серверу нет. Администратор кинул этот ключ.

Comment: Тогда возможно это и есть приватный ключ (который id_rsa) и его публичная часть уже лежит на сервере. Что там в начале файла? Покажите первые строчки

Comment: -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54994641/4827341

Comment: @Igor Нужно от Вас уточнение. Закрытый ключ сервера (sshd) или закрытый ключ клиента на сервере ?

Comment: Вам администратор скорее всего уже сгенерировал пару, и положил публичный ключ куда надо. Вам нужен приватный для соединения. Но вообще-то надо в таком случае менять парольную фразу, а лучше и саму пару.

Answer (score 1):

Ключи всегда генерируются парой открытый/закрытый и это просто два файла например ida_rsa.pub/ida_rsa
Поэтому  можно взять закрытый ключ (файл ida_rsa) с сервера и положить на клиент, а на  сервер публичный ключ (файл ida_rsa.pub) добавить в файл authorized_keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -i /путь/id_rsa -l user 192.168.0.1
```

Но публичная часть должна быть прописанна `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Где user имя пользователя на сервере, возможно, root.